# Loop audio with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I have the next code

```
var audioElement0 = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement0.setAttribute('src', 'notify.wav');
audioElement0.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement0.Play(); 

var audioElement1 = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement1.setAttribute('src', 'notify.wav');
audioElement1.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement1.Play(); 

var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement2.setAttribute('src', 'notify.wav');
audioElement2.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
audioElement2.Play();
```

but it only plays once... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have the loop property:

`audioElement.loop=true;`

But some browsers do not support well the loop property, you can add an event listener like this:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `loop="loop"` attribute in the audio tag.

Answer (score 2):

The `audio` element has a `loop` boolean property that you can set to auto-loop its playback. Another option would be to add and event listener which responds to the "ended" event of the audio element. In  your handler, set the position of the audio back to 0, and play anew.