# Loop an audio file between 2 looping points with Web Audio API (seamless)

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I know how to play an audio file with Web Audio API from an array buffer (coming from RAW 16 bit audio data, for example WAV file):

```
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 1;
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(globalGainNode);
source.start();
```

How to make a "seamless" looping between 2 looping points?

Example:

```
0                 loop_start                loop_end
|-----------------|-------------------------|
                  [========= LOOP ==========]
```

The playback should be seamless in this order:

- `0` to `loop_start` (this "attack" part of the sound is played only once)
- `loop_start` to `loop_end`
- `loop_start` to `loop_end`
- `loop_start` to `loop_end`
- ... forever

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Loop audio with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610638/loop-audio-with-javascript) since here, a `loop` attribute for an `<audio>` tag won't help: 1) I don't use an `<audio>` tag but rather a WebAudioAPI buffer, 2) and anyway the `loop` property loops from t=0, and here we want to loop from `loop_start`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [loopStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loopStart) and [loopEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loopEnd) properties of the [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) that you're creating to the timestamps you want, just ensure their accuracy is big enough to give you the exact sample you want:

```js
const source = this.context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer;
source.loopStart = 12.3456789;  // Time in seconds
source.loopEnd = 23.45678;      // Time in seconds 
source.loop = true;
source.start();
```

Comment: And MDN even provides a working [example loop](https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/) which appears "seamless" to me. +1